# Remove all empty keys in a nested dictionary (via yield)

Tags: python

I have the following function to remove keys with an empty value or that start with an underscore. It works on a non-nested dictionary:

```
def _remove_missing_and_underscored_keys(d):
    if not d: return d
    for key in d.keys():
        if not d.get(key):
            del d[key]
        elif key.startswith('_'):
            del d[key]

    return d

d = {"Name": "David",
    "_Age": 50,
    "Numbers": [1,2,3,4,5],
    "Height": ""
}

>>> _remove_missing_and_underscored_keys(d)
{'Name': 'David', 'Numbers': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]}
```

However, I would like to create the above so that it can remove nested items as well. I believe I need to use a yield statement for this, but I'm not having luck with implementing it properly. Here is an example of what I want it to do:

```
d = {
    "PlatformID": "B00EU7XL9Q",
    "Platform": "Amazon",
    "Type": "Collection",
    "Products": {
        "UK": {
            "URL": "http://www.amazon.co.uk/dp/B00EU7XL9Q",
            "Rating": None,
            "_IsAudited": True,
            "Offers": {
                "HDBUY": {
                    "Currency": "GBP",
                    "FutureReleaseStartDate": None,
                    "Cost": "14.99",
                    "IsFutureRelease": False
                },
                "SDBUY": {
                    "Currency": "GBP",
                    "FutureReleaseStartDate": None,
                    "Cost": "14.99",
                    "IsFutureRelease": False
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

---

```
>>> _remove_missing_and_underscored_keys(d)
{
    "PlatformID": "B00EU7XL9Q",
    "Platform": "Amazon",
    "Type": "Collection",
    "Products": {
        "UK": {
            "URL": "http://www.amazon.co.uk/dp/B00EU7XL9Q",
            "Offers": {
                "HDBUY": {
                    "Currency": "GBP",
                    "Cost": "14.99",
                },
                "SDBUY": {
                    "Currency": "GBP",
                    "Cost": "14.99",
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

In other words, it will do the above operation on all nested levels of the dict.

Comment: Did you mean I will need to use recursion?

Comment: hahaha, yes that is the answer, do something like if type(value) == dict:
value= _remove_missing_and_underscored_keys(value) and you are done (INSIDE _remove_missing_and_underscored_keys)

Comment: In python 3 your code throws an error, "dictionary changed size during iteration", Skam's answer below solves that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
def _remove_missing_and_underscored_keys(d):
    if not d: return d
    for key in d.keys():
        if not d.get(key):
            del d[key]
        elif key.startswith('_'):
            del d[key]
        elif type(d[key]) == dict:
            d[key] = _remove_missing_and_underscored_keys(d[key])

    return d
```

Comment: Oh that's so simple, thanks for that hint I can't believe I didn't see that initially.

Comment: Happy to help :)

Comment: @E.Serra it might also make sense to have a parameter whether to return the original dict or a copy of it, such as `if use_copy is True: d=deepcopy(d)`.

Answer (score 3):

You can use recursion with a dictionary comprehension:

```
d = {'PlatformID': 'B00EU7XL9Q', 'Platform': 'Amazon', 'Type': 'Collection', 'Products': {'UK': {'URL': 'http://www.amazon.co.uk/dp/B00EU7XL9Q', 'Rating': None, '_IsAudited': True, 'Offers': {'HDBUY': {'Currency': 'GBP', 'FutureReleaseStartDate': None, 'Cost': '14.99', 'IsFutureRelease': False}, 'SDBUY': {'Currency': 'GBP', 'FutureReleaseStartDate': None, 'Cost': '14.99', 'IsFutureRelease': False}}}}}
def _del(_d):
  return {a:_del(b) if isinstance(b, dict) else b for a, b in _d.items() if b and not a.startswith('_')}
```

---

```
import json
print(json.dumps(_del(d), indent=4))
```

Output:

```
{
 "PlatformID": "B00EU7XL9Q",
 "Platform": "Amazon",
 "Type": "Collection",
 "Products": {
    "UK": {
        "URL": "http://www.amazon.co.uk/dp/B00EU7XL9Q",
        "Offers": {
            "HDBUY": {
                "Currency": "GBP",
                "Cost": "14.99"
            },
            "SDBUY": {
                "Currency": "GBP",
                "Cost": "14.99"
            }
        }
     }
   }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I think you meant to say, you needed to use recursion to solve this. I don't think using a generator quite solves your problem. 
Another caveat is that you shouldn't iterate through a variable you are changing. That's why I create the copy `_d` modify and return that and iterate through the original structure.

```
import pprint

def _remove_missing_and_underscored_keys(d):
    if not d: return d
    _d = d.copy()
    for key in _d.keys():
        if not _d.get(key):
            del d[key]
        elif key.startswith('_'):
            del d[key]
        elif isinstance(_d[key], dict):
            _remove_missing_and_underscored_keys(_d[key])
    return _d

_d = {
    "PlatformID": "B00EU7XL9Q",
    "Platform": "Amazon",
    "Type": "Collection",
    "Products": {
        "UK": {
            "URL": "http://www.amazon.co.uk/dp/B00EU7XL9Q",
            "Rating": None,
            "_IsAudited": True,
            "Offers": {
                "HDBUY": {
                    "Currency": "GBP",
                    "FutureReleaseStartDate": None,
                    "Cost": "14.99",
                    "IsFutureRelease": False
                },
                "SDBUY": {
                    "Currency": "GBP",
                    "FutureReleaseStartDate": None,
                    "Cost": "14.99",
                    "IsFutureRelease": False
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
foo = _remove_missing_and_underscored_keys(_d)
pprint.pprint(foo)
```

Output:

```
 {'Platform': 'Amazon',
 'PlatformID': 'B00EU7XL9Q',
 'Products': {'UK': {'Offers': {'HDBUY': {'Cost': '14.99', 'Currency': 'GBP'},
                                'SDBUY': {'Cost': '14.99', 'Currency': 'GBP'}},
                     'URL': 'http://www.amazon.co.uk/dp/B00EU7XL9Q'}},
 'Type': 'Collection'}
```

Comment: If you are using recursion, and everything is single threaded, no way you will be iterating something that is being changed. You will just iterate, find a key, and then recursively change the contents inside it, that no one else would touch

Comment: @skam -- thanks, wouldn't you need to use `deepcopy` instead of `copy` though if it's a nested dict? Or do they both do the same thing here.

Answer (score 1):

Just go recursive.

Add another check to see if a value in primary dict is a dict, and call the same function on it.

```
# your code goes here
def _remove_missing_and_underscored_keys(d):
    if not d: return d
    for key in d.keys():
        if not d.get(key):
            del d[key]
        elif key.startswith('_'):
            del d[key]
        elif type(d[key]) is dict:
            #print("key '{}' stores a dict '{}', need to cleanup recursively".format(key, d[key]))
            d[key] = _remove_missing_and_underscored_keys(d[key])
            # Keep below check if you want to treat empty dict as `empty` as well
            if d[key] == None or d[key] == {}:
                del d[key]

    return d

d = {
    "PlatformID": "B00EU7XL9Q",
    "Platform": "Amazon",
    "Type": "Collection",
    "Products": {
        "UK": {
            "URL": "http://www.amazon.co.uk/dp/B00EU7XL9Q",
            "Rating": None,
            "_IsAudited": True,
            "Offers": {
                "HDBUY": {
                    "Currency": "GBP",
                    "FutureReleaseStartDate": None,
                    "Cost": "14.99",
                    "IsFutureRelease": False
                },
                "SDBUY": {
                    "Currency": "GBP",
                    "FutureReleaseStartDate": None,
                    "Cost": "14.99",
                    "IsFutureRelease": False
                },
                "x" : {
                    "y":None
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

e = _remove_missing_and_underscored_keys(d)
print(e)
```

See it in action: https://ideone.com/5xDDZl

Above code also handles empty dicts stored at any key or any dict that became empty after recursively cleaning it. You can remove that check if needed.